# Calculation of water pressure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

I have a water tank of 750Ltr capacity installed at a height of 7.5M from ground. How to determine the range of pressure gauge required to measure the pressure from ground level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To calculate pressure at point in a vertical water pipe of given diameter](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19547/)